# After Decompilation My Java File contain Byte Code

Tags: java, decompiling

I have decompiled jar file using JD GUI Java decompiler . Only one file contain not actual java code it contain byte code ....how to get rid of this?

```
public String loginAtStartup(String cmd, String dn, String loginId,
String passwd, String tserver, String port, int retry) { 

// Byte code:
    //   0: getstatic
84\011com/ibm/nisource/softphone/SoftPhone:log\011Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;
    //   3: new 196\011java/lang/StringBuffer
    //   6: dup
    //   7: ldc_w 439
    //   10: invokespecial
201\011java/lang/StringBuffer:<init>\011(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //   13: getstatic
72\011com/ibm/nisource/softphone/SoftPhone:props\011Ljava/util/Properties;
    //   16: ldc_w 441
    //   19: invokevirtual
185\011java/util/Properties:getProperty\011(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   22: invokevirtual
205\011java/lang/StringBuffer:append\011(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
    //   25: ldc_w 443
    //   28: invokevirtual
205\011java/lang/StringBuffer:append\011(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
```

and i want to have java code instead of this ...why this bytecode was not converted to Java Code ? and how to get Java Code from this ??

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the `.class` file has been [obfuscated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) and some decompilers get confused when they see obfuscated code and cannot decompile the `.class` file correctly.

Comment: then any solution for that ??

Comment: @Nisarg Mehta - buy the company that created the IP you are trying to (umm) steal.  (OK, maybe that's not how see what you are trying to do.  But the point is that the code was obfuscated to PREVENT you reverse engineering it, and what you are doing is morally and legally questionable.)

Comment: Stephen,i m not trying to steal anything.I have started supporting one application which was supported by resigned person.I need to compare to jar file source code .that's why i am looking for source code...the jar file which i want to convert is our own...I am not trying to steal anything...